# Rolling user calculations on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, rolling-computation

I do rolling calculations on `dataframe`. On each row I check if all `high` values, which are inside the range specified by "from-to" values, are below current `level` value. `from` and `to` values are index borders from some previous index labels. The only way I found is to use `apply` and `lambda` combination with `axis=1`. It works but makes the code very slow. Is there any faster way to do this? Thank you in advance!

```
df['cond'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df.loc[x['from']:x['to'], 'high'] <= x['level']).all(), axis=1)
```

Final result looks like this:

```
                      high    level   from                  to                    cond
2021-01-04 00:00:00   1162.97 1162.97 2020-10-06 00:00:00   2021-01-04 00:00:00   True
2021-01-05 00:00:00   1134.6  1162.97 2020-10-06 00:00:00   2021-01-04 00:00:00   True
2021-01-06 00:00:00   1213    1162.97 2020-10-06 00:00:00   2021-01-04 00:00:00   True
2021-01-07 00:00:00   1289    1289    2020-10-09 00:00:00   2021-01-07 00:00:00   True
2021-01-08 00:00:00   1273.75 1289    2020-10-09 00:00:00   2021-01-07 00:00:00   True
2021-01-09 00:00:00   1304.37 1289    2020-10-09 00:00:00   2021-01-07 00:00:00   True
2021-01-10 00:00:00   1348.33 1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-11 00:00:00   1260    1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-12 00:00:00   1150.02 1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-13 00:00:00   1137.65 1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-14 00:00:00   1247.55 1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-15 00:00:00   1256.98 1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-16 00:00:00   1298    1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-17 00:00:00   1269.02 1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-18 00:00:00   1260.75 1348.33 2020-10-12 00:00:00   2021-01-10 00:00:00   True
2021-01-19 00:00:00   1438.3  1438.3  2020-10-21 00:00:00   2021-01-19 00:00:00   True
2021-01-20 00:00:00   1407.93 1438.3  2020-10-21 00:00:00   2021-01-19 00:00:00   True
2021-01-21 00:00:00   1390    1438.3  2020-10-21 00:00:00   2021-01-19 00:00:00   True
2021-01-22 00:00:00   1273.79 1438.3  2020-10-21 00:00:00   2021-01-19 00:00:00   True
2021-01-23 00:00:00   1272.44 1438.3  2020-10-21 00:00:00   2021-01-19 00:00:00   True
2021-01-24 00:00:00   1398.83 1438.3  2020-10-21 00:00:00   2021-01-19 00:00:00   True
2021-01-25 00:00:00   1475    1475    2020-10-27 00:00:00   2021-01-25 00:00:00   True
2021-01-26 00:00:00   1378.49 1475    2020-10-27 00:00:00   2021-01-25 00:00:00   True
2021-01-27 00:00:00   1373.9  1475    2020-10-27 00:00:00   2021-01-25 00:00:00   True
2021-01-28 00:00:00   1360    1475    2020-10-27 00:00:00   2021-01-25 00:00:00   True
2021-01-29 00:00:00   1436.9  1475    2020-10-27 00:00:00   2021-01-25 00:00:00   True
2021-01-30 00:00:00   1406    1475    2020-10-27 00:00:00   2021-01-25 00:00:00   True
2021-01-31 00:00:00   1380.74 1475    2020-10-27 00:00:00   2021-01-25 00:00:00   True
```

Comment: Can you provide a example dataset?

Comment: To get the highest previous values, you could use `.cummax()`, instead of needing to use `.apply` for it.

Comment: @mozway I added the result above

Comment: @S Rawson `high` column is already given

Comment: @Ruslan please provide the data as text

Comment: @mozway I changed the format to text